# W3TC manual cache flush does not work

Tags: actions, cache

My need is to have a `.php` file that is located in the root folders of all WordPress websites I manage, which can flush all cache of all sites.

Therefore, I created a file "flush-cache.php" in the root folder of the first website, and I added the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Flushing the W3TC Plugin's Cache entirely, and specifically, also page cache (as it does not seem to be part of flush-all)
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

ignore_user_abort( true );

/* Don't make the request block till we finish, if possible. */
if ( function_exists( 'fastcgi_finish_request' ) && version_compare( phpversion(), '7.0.16', '>=' ) ) {
    fastcgi_finish_request();
}

if ( ! empty( $_POST ) || defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || defined( 'DOING_CRON' ) ) {
    die();
}

// Flush W3TC Cache right now
function flush_w3tc_cache() {
    $w3_plugin_totalcache->flush_all();
}
add_action( 'wp', 'flush_w3tc_cache' );

function flush_w3tc_page() {
    $w3_plugin_totalcache->flush_pgcache();
}
add_action( 'wp', 'flush_w3tc_page' );
// END Flush W3TC Cache right now
```

I found most of it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509492/w3-total-cache-clear-page-cache-every-hour-automatic

However, when I open the file https://domain.xyz/flush-cache.php, it does not seem to work. I don't get an error message or any other output (expected), but in the backend of that site, I still see that the page cache needs to be cleared.

Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Comment: You can't call WordPress functions without requiring wp-load. However you ought to get some error output for this. Are you hitting the die(), e.g. are you requesting the page with a GET? It might be worth adding some trace output. (And some security to the endpoint.)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Rup I am simply opening the php file in my browser. The code I posted is the entire code I have in the file (no die() anywhere). How do I add a trace output? And security? 
I'd like to mention that this solution is maybe a bit of an overkill? After reading this link (http://tiny.cc/m0iq9y) I tried just adding `<?php $w3_plugin_totalcache->flush_all(); ?>` to a new php file, but there I get an error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function flush_all() on null in ... <file name>".

Comment: You've got `! empty( $_POST )` which I think means this code will only work if you post a form to it, not just open the page in your browser. Trace: you can just add `echo "in the die() block";` to your script or e.g. `print_r($_POST);` to dump out variables, and you'll see this output when you load the page. Your new file: yes, you'll have to `require('wp-load.php');` or `require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );` before you can use WordPress functions. I'm not sure if that's enough to load all the plugins or if you'll have to e.g. hook 'wp' as your original code does.

Comment: I've tried the following: (1) added `echo "<p>" . "hello" . "</p>";` before the if statement to see if there's any output and there is not, (2) added `print_r($_POST);` but there is also no output, (3) added `echo $_POST;` inside the if before the die() but there is no output, (4) added `require('wp-load.php');` before the function calls, but there is no output and the result is unchanged (the page cache is still not flushed). Should I add an answer with the entire code?
It seems strange to me that there is no output at all when opening the php file.

Comment: ... and I will remove `! empty( $_POST ) ||` from the code, as I don't need it, it will just stop the code in case there's no form posted to it.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to hook wp for the flush: the event might not be fired in this situation, or it might already be fired. So you can possibly just call the `$w3_plugin_totalcache` functions from the top level of the script. I've tested this and I get a 500 error unless I `require('wp-load.php');` and I do get any `echo` s output, but I don't get the wp events called (I don't think).

Comment: My code looks like this now: ```<?php
/**
 * Flushing the W3TC Plugin's Cache entirely, and specifically, also page cache (as it does not seem to be part of flush-all)
 * @package WordPress
 */
ignore_user_abort( true );
require('wp-load.php');
$w3_plugin_totalcache->flush_pgcache();
$w3_plugin_totalcache->flush_all();``` but it is still not purging the cache. I also get a 500 error.
Very odd. The file is in the root directory of WP, in the same as wp-load.php.

Answer (score 1):

The working solution is:

```
<?php
/*
 * Flushing the W3TC Plugin's Cache entirely
 * @package WordPress
 */
ignore_user_abort( true );
include('/home/clients/<client-directory>/<website-directory>' . '/wp-load.php');
w3tc_flush_all();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a tool that can flush multiple W3TC websites simultaneously using one password-protected control panel. It’s available on Github, if this could help anyone: https://github.com/web-butler/w3tc-remote-flush-multiple